# Smtp Client MVC not working in register method

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asp.net-identity, smtpclient

I'm hey one of the most weirdest problems i have seen until now. I have the same peace of code the SMTP client. I have it in a separate class that handles sending emails so this is the constructor`

```
// Setting the smtp info
            smtpClient = new SmtpClient("xxxxxxx", 587);
        // Setting the no reply email address
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxx");
        FromMailAddress = new MailAddress("xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");

        // Setting Ssl
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;`
```

And this is for sending the Email:

```
     // Setting a new email address for the recver
        MailAddress reciver = new MailAddress("xxxxxxxx");

        // Creating a new Email message
        MailMessage email = new MailMessage();

        email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        email.To.Add(reciver);
        email.From = FromMailAddress;
        email.Subject = "Email confomation link";
        email.Body = "Please Fonfurm your email by pressing this link: <a href=\"" + callBackUrl + "\">link</a>";

        smtpClient.Send(email);
```

Sorry i really needed to block out some stuff. But this code works in a test application that i made in just simple comandline C# application. Now comes the strange thing when i call it in a simple ActionResult that i created for this it works but when i call it in Register method it fails it says time out, and for the rest it does not give anymore information. Here is the test method i created:

```
    public ActionResult SendTestEmail()
    {
        new EmailManager().SendEmailConfirmation("xxxxxxxx", "Hello world");

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Quite simple and it works but when i put it like this it fails:

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        // Check if model is valled And if we have a id
        if (ModelState.IsValid && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.RegisterCode))
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email.ToLower() };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Sing in
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                // Add the members role to the user
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Member");

                // Createing a token for email confermation
                string emailCode = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

                // Createing a URL
                string callbackUrl = Url.Action(
                    "ConfirmEmail",
                    "Account",
                    new { userId = user.Id, code = emailCode },
                    protocol: Request.Url.Scheme
                    );

                // Sending the email
                new EmailManager().SendEmailConfirmation(model.Email, callbackUrl);

                // delete the registion code form the database
                GenerateCodeManager.DeleteFromCodeFromDatabase(model.RegisterCode);

                // Return to index
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

And than we have a problem it fails. I really dont know why i think this also might the problem why my web server is also not sending emails. i use the SMTP of zoho That is this SMTP smtp.zoho.eu Like i said it works but not in this method.

Comment: **Could you please show us where exactly your error is happening?** Are you still getting an error if you pass arguments manually (ex: `new EmailManager().SendEmailConfirmation("xxxxxxxx", "Hello world");`)?

Comment: Ohh yea at smtpClient.Send(email); Sorry for not lissting that.

Comment: `smtpClient.Send(email);` doesn't exist in your last method (which you state has the problem)...